# How to create a nether portal (and collect required resorces) in skyblock

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing skyblock 1.1 - no obsidian in the starter chest.

I'm also playing in minecraft version 1.7.10.

I understand in 1.7 you can make obsidian with Redstone, lava and water. This seems like a bit of a glitch (it's been removed in 1.8 I think). Is there any other way to build a nether portal in skyblock?

Comment: Water on lava gives obsidian. That's how it works in Minecraft from a long time.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The infinite obsidian glitch which allowed you to convert redstone (dropped by witches) into obsidian was fixed in the 1.8 patch.

There is currently no way to acquire obsidian without pouring water on a lava source block, travelling to the end, or already being able to travel to the nether. Since there is no way to acquire more obsidian or lava legitimately, it is impossible to build a portal.

Comment: He's playing 1.7.10, as he stated, thus the glitch will work for him. Also, it seems like he has access to lava if he's considering using the redstone trick. If not, then yes there is no way to make a portal.

Answer (score 0):

In skyblock, there are 3 "blocks". The first is a grass block, with one tree, and a chest containing an ice block and a bucket of lava. You can use this to create an infinite cobble generator.

There should be another island off in the distance. This "block" should be made of sand, and has a cactus, and another chest containing 10 obsidian blocks, and another bucket.

Using the obsidian found in the chest, you can make a portal.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. A portal would require 10 still lava, A.K.A. the 10 obsidian, and flint and steel. In regular skyblock you cannot get any of them. So, no, you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can without flint and steel. Just get a wooden plank block and set it on fire with lava right next to the base of the portal and youre good to go.

Answer (score 0):

From 1.17 onwards, wandering traders now trade [pointed dripstone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pointed_Dripstone). In combination with a cauldron -and the lava you already have- you can create more lava with it. Placing the lava and solidifying it with water will allow you to build a portal frame.

The old wood and lava trick can be used to ignite the portal.